# My website crashes without the PDB files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

I have a web application that works fine on my development machine but when I install it on another machine, it just crashes on one of the new methods I added to a DLL.

Looking deeper into it, the installed does not take the PDB files whereas they are on my dev machine. So I tried to remove them on the dev machine and my new method crashes the same. Other methods don't crash at all.

My method just throws up a "NullPointerException" that never comes up when the PDB files are present.

I know what the PDB files are for (I searched this site before posting) but this should not alter the way the application works. Should it?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that all is in `<release>` not `<debug>`. That is why I question about the PDB files.

Comment: Are you running release version of your binaries? I didn't think having the PDB files were required for running debug distribution, but it's a thought. Also is your web.config file set to allow debug? I wonder if IIS requires PDB if you've turned on stack trace support.

Comment: There could be many more differences between the environments - what makes you think it's due to the missing PDBs? Does it crash if you remove the PDBs on your development machine? Does it not crash if you put the PDBs on the problematic machine?

Comment: Staying on the dev machine, my IIS points to my work folder. So I copied the folder to a different location on the dev machine, set it up in IIS. Works fine, then I remove the PDB files and set <debug="false"> in web.config and it crashes on the new methods.

Comment: NullPointerException is not .NET/IIS native. You have to collect the crash stack trace. I suspect your code base indeed asks for PDB files under the hood, so you have to debug carefully. Common sense as others mentioned might not apply to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what is going wrong in my code.
In the logger part, using log4Net, I have code like this:

```
public static void Info(string strMsg)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
    _log.Info(string.Format("{0,-25} L{1:0000} {2}", sf.GetFileName().Substring(sf.GetFileName().LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1), sf.GetFileLineNumber(), strMsg));
}
```

So I changed the entries to something like this:

```
public static void Debug(string strMsg)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
#if DEBUG
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
    _log.Debug(string.Format("{0,-25} L{1:0000} {2}", sf.GetFileName().Substring(sf.GetFileName().LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1), sf.GetFileLineNumber(), strMsg));
#else
    _log.Debug(string.Format("{0}",strMsg));
#endif            
}
```

And now all works fine without the PDB files.
So picking information from the stacktrace requires PDB files.

Comment: You would be well to look into [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) and other Caller* attributes. Fetching stack trace is very time consuming operation and should be avoided in normal application workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @NikolaRadosavljević I'll check that for next move. In fact the code was there before me. Will using [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) return the same result as the `StackTrace` but without needing the PDB files?

Comment: I checked the CompilerServices and the CallerMemberNameAttribute is a .Net4.5 whereas my code is .Net3.5 and I can't upgrade per my own will.